# WCF, EF and UWP

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, uwp

I'm currently in the process of writing a UWP application. I'm using a WCF Service to talk to a Business Layer that contains EF to talk to the SQL Server database. It's all in the very early stages as I've never used UWP before.

I got the UWP to consume the WCF to return data from the DB. This was working fine when I returned a string. However, now that I want to return objects this is no longer working in the sense that UWP just receives a reference. No object is returned. When I run the WCF in debug mode, the object is returned and I can see all the fields with data etc.

Could one of you geniuses help me, as I'm stuck and don't know what to do.

Here is my code. My class in Business Layer

```
namespace Business.Models
{
  [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
  public class SystemUser
  {
    public tblSystemUser User { get; set; }

    // public tblRole Role { get; set; }

  }
}
```

WCF code:

```
namespace ActiveCareWCF
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IUser
  {

    [OperationContract]
    Task<SystemUser> DoLogin(string userName);
  }


 public class Service : IUser
 {
    public async Task<SystemUser> DoLogin(string userName)
    {
        SystemUser systemUser = new SystemUser();
        userName = @"username";

        try
        {
            ServiceCalls serviceCalls = new ServiceCalls();

            systemUser = serviceCalls.AuthorizeUser(userName);

            return systemUser --- **this is returning an object**;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```

The SVC file:

```
 public class ActiveCareService : IUser
{
    public async Task<SystemUser> DoLogin(string userName)
    {
        Service service = new Service();

        var user = service.DoLogin(userName);

        return user.Result;
    }

}
```

And finally the call in UWP.

```
 private async void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveCareService.UserClient client = new ActiveCareService.UserClient();

        var userFromService = client.DoLoginAsync(@"username").Result;
        await client.CloseAsync();

        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Logged in as " + userFromService.FirstName); **This just returns a string of the type of object it is, not the actual object. This is what I'm struggling with.**
        await dialog.ShowAsync();

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourSites));
    }
```

[image: This is what is returned in the WCF service.]

Thanks in advance.

[image: And this is what is then returned when called from UWP.]

Comment: Update your service client in your UWP app?

Comment: Hi Dave, I've updated and removed and re-added. All the call in UWP returns is {ActiveCareApp.ActiveCareService.SystemUser}.

Comment: do you have a demo project that shows the problem that you can show?

Comment: Hi Dave, I cannot provide a demo project, but I will update my original questions with some screenshots of what is being returned and where.

Comment: Lots of issues here.  1) do you really need WCF? Not directly wrong but a little heavy and outdated. Alternatives are, a.o, WebAPI and ServiceStack.

Comment: 2) Does your tblUser need IsReference? Ie, does a User refer to other users?

Comment: 3) your `async void Login_Click()` shouldn't use `.Result`. Use `await` instead.

Comment: 4) _"UWP just receives a reference"_ doesn't really mean anything. And _"in debug mode ... I can see all the fields with data"_ is strange then. How is the `tblSystemUser` linked to / shared between client and server projects?

Comment: Is this a UWP issue or a service config issue? I'd tell by looking at what is in the raw HTTP if you call the endpoint directly.

Comment: What I suspect here, is UWP app able to decipher the SOAP messages what is generally returned by the WCF unless it is configured as json/REST. If that is the case, probably you can re-organize your architecture and transformed the object to proper format before it reaches the UWP layer. You are able to read string because this is the default common serialized data type.

Comment: whats the Business Layer project type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing, for now my services always return JSON strings, it means must serialize in service and deserialize at uwp.

You must have the model of serialized classes both at service and UWP. It works pretty well.

At My service I have a full Model and at UWP app I create a reduced model that matches with my needs.

Hope this can help.